# NOT LIKE clause not working in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, moodle, sql-like

I am trying to list all the courses for a person, where the course code doesn't start with a 'C'.  The following code is still bring up 'C-...' codes.  Any idea how to fix it?

```
SELECT u.idnumber, u.firstname, u.lastname, r.id, c.idnumber AS m_name, c.id AS c_id
FROM mdl_user u
  LEFT JOIN mdl_role_assignments r ON u.id = r.userid
  LEFT JOIN mdl_context c1 ON r.contextid = c1.id
  LEFT JOIN mdl_course c ON c1.instanceid = c.id
WHERE u.idnumber = 'a.smoth' AND NOT c.id LIKE 'C%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the `NOT`just before the `LIKE`:

```
... c.id NOT LIKE 'C%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You not like syntax is not correct use it:

```
SELECT u.idnumber,u.firstname,u.lastname,r.id,c.idnumber AS m_name,c.id AS c_id
       FROM mdl_user u
            LEFT JOIN mdl_role_assignments r ON u.id = r.userid
            LEFT JOIN mdl_context c1 ON r.contextid = c1.id
            LEFT JOIN mdl_course c ON c1.instanceid = c.id
            WHERE u.idnumber = 'a.smoth' AND c.id NOT LIKE 'C%'
                                                  ^^^
```

This is [NOT LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_not-like) clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
WHERE u.idnumber = 'a.smoth' AND c.id NOT LIKE 'C%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE u.idnumber = 'a.smoth' AND c.id NOT LIKE 'C%'
```